# How to get the sum of credits to show in console.log() using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my variable: I need the sum of credits to be shown in console.log() how do I do this?

```
var people=[
{name:"Matthew",yearBorn:"1927",yearPassed:"2003",credits:"11"},
{name:"Jeremy",yearBorn:"1947",yearPassed:"",credits:"82"},
{name:"Todd",yearBorn:"1957",yearPassed:"1989",credits:"72"},
{name:"Aaron",yearBorn:"1929",yearPassed:"",credits:"15"}
];
```

Comment: Usually it's best if you post what code you've tried so we know we're not answering pasted in homework problems.  Some different ways if you're not sure how to get started: use a for loop to go over every element in the array and add their credits to a variable that starts at 0.  Use `Number()` to convert the strings so addition works properly.  If you want a more streamlined way to do it look into the array `reduce` method.

Comment: An answer below recommended the excellent resource [What Have You Tried](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/), which is better as a comment. I recommend it too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, nice name. I'm guessing you joined just for this?

Use a foreach loop and iterate over all the values adding them to a variable.

```
let total_credit = 0;
people.forEach((person) => {
   total_credit += parseInt(person[“credits”])
} 
console.log(total_credit);
```

Comment: Just one change to what guardin has mentioned, typecast string to number

Comment: You can also do `total_credit += parseInt(person[“credits”])`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a variable to store the total number of credits in. The keys in your data can just be directly accessed by their name, e.g. `people[0].credits`. You go through each "people" in your variable and add that value to the total number of credits.

```
var Credits = 0; 
for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) { 
    Credits += parseInt(people[i].credits); 
}
```

Note also that you have to convert the value to a integer because you encapsulated it in quotes. Otherwise you'll just get 11827215 :P

Comment: Good answer! Small bit of advice - answers can be thought of as being for a broad audience, rather than just the question author. On that basis we tend to trim advice about how to write questions, since we hope most readers know this already. The advice in this case was very good, so I have copied it to a comment under the question. You only need a couple more upvotes to be able to do that yourself `:=)`.